# Why does html code appear in frontend content of static block?

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block, wysiwyg

I have a problem with the static block content. The WYSIWYG Editor is enabled by default. The text in the static block content displays properly in the admin but when this page is loaded in the frontend the html code appears in the content of the static block.

How can I troubleshoot this?

http://www.screencast.com/t/jZZxNyRQ6

http://www.screencast.com/t/Ni9vUa9B

Comment: is it just doing it there or everywhere on the site?

Comment: Are you putting the content inside a textarea form object or <pre> tags ? If you are that will not render HTML

Comment: It is only doing this in one particular cms block.

Comment: How are you displaying it on the page?  What is your php code to show it and what is the resultant HTML (as if you were doing a view source) ?

Comment: It is displayed through an extension - I will contact the developer; maybe some bug, but it was not an issue until we updated some text. For 2 months it has been installed with no problem.

Comment: Good luck.  It might be that the content is being written to the screen after being processed with htmlspecialchars()  or htmlentities() .  Take a look in your template - has that been modified recently?